# How can I activate Java and the Java Console in Safari?

Tags: java, plugins, safari, applet, console

I just spent hours finding out how to activate Java and the Java Console in Safari, and nothing I could find on the Web was helpful for me, so I thought I'd ask this as a question here and answer it in case others have the same problem:

> I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8 and using Safari Version 5.1.1 (6534.51.22).
>   Java applets don't seem to load, and the Java Console doesn't open
>   even though I followed all the instructions I found online on how to
>   activate it, such as opening the Java Preferences in
>   Applications/Utilities and selecting the "show console" radio button
>   on the "advanced" tab. What else can I do?

Comment: +1, I hate when you visit a forum and someone has the same issue as you, and he finally replies with "nvm, figured it out". Thank you :)

Comment: @PeekaySwitch  It is intriguing that you should post a glowing review of this question, mention '+1', but not give it an up-vote!  What gives?

Comment: Well, I have no idea how valid the question actually is, as I don't use Safari or Java Console. I applaud your effort, but I'm in no position to know if it's actually relevant to other persons.

Comment: @PeekaySwitch: Just to clarify, since the "your" in your comment seems to imply that you may have thought that the comment you were replying to was from me -- it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether plugins are enabled in the security tab of the Safari preferences. Even if Java is enabled in the Safari preferences and the Java Console is enabled in the Java Preferences, apparently neither of them work if plugins are disabled.

Comment: Remember to restart Safari after enabling it…